# JetBrains dotTrace unable to trace remote after local client unexpected restart

Tags: asp.net, iis, dottrace

I've been successfully using dotTrace for a while, but surprisingly this is the first time this has happened: I was using dotTrace to trace a remote server for about half an hour, when my local machine (performing/collecting the trace data) unexpectedly restarted.

I tried restarting RemoteAgent on the remote machine (starts fine), and I can pull it up in dotTrace's Remote tab, but I can't get dotTrace to re-attach to the remote IIS process. I get the following error every time I click "Run" to start the trace:

> Failed to start profiling: Can't start profiling. Details:
>
> Profiler is unable to attach to the process: Please ensure the process is not run under another profiler, performance monitoring tool, mocking tool, or try and reboot the computer.

Is there any way to "recover" a profiling session? This is an active server, so I'd really rather not reboot the entire machine, or kill the IIS process, unless absolutely necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there is no way to recover the session, you need to restart IIS process. dotTrace can't do anything if detach from an application wasn't performed.

Answer (score 0):

As Konkat mentioned, there was no way to recover the session data. We had to wait until after business hours to end the IIS process hosting that app, restart it, and then restart the dotTrace remote client.